# Spring jpa repository find all

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-rest, jackson-databind

I'm trying to execute this method:

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public Iterable<AspsortObject> getallasp()
{
    return ar.findAll();
}
```

but I get this error:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:722) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
```

my repository :

```
@Repository
public interface AspsortRepositori extends CrudRepository<AspsortObject,Long>{

    @Override
    List<AspsortObject> findAll();

}
```

What should I to do to resolve this error and show all data in my front end parti?

Comment: this also happens when your pojo field is not matching with the json field

Comment: why are you returning Iterable<AspsortObject> rather than List<AspsortObject> from your get API

Comment: Can you show your db table and your entity class?

Comment: @ELMANDPURAMINE Just don't override the method and change return type from `Iterable` to `List<AspsortObject>`.

Comment: I think problem is the `AspsortObject`,can you give definition of it.In my application I override the `findAll` method but works well。

Answer (score 0):

Hello when i added @JsonIgnore in my  entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aspsortobject")
public class AspsortObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rfpid")
    private Rfpobject rfpid;
    private String requestid;
    private String aspart;
    private String aspname;
    private String asporganisation;
    private String aspsort;
    public AspsortObject() {
        super();
    }
```

Comment: @InsertKnowledge  this is my entity please can you help me to resolve this probleme